# Dummy Variable Control for Inflationary Time Period

Tags: panel-data, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I estimated a panel data model (U.S. states observed across 10 years) with a dummy variable to control for an inflationary period like 1973-1974 across all states. Is it possible to include year fixed effects too? Also, does it matter of the fixed panel is balanced or not?

Comment: The 1973/1973 dummy would be collinear with the year effects.  It's redundant -- just include the year effects to wash out level effects of years.  My concern in such a situation is that different years follow different DGP's, and as such marginal effects of regressors of interest will vary in the population.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I am actually going to look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you actually can do this. The random effect necessarily estimates residual variability after control of fixed effects. The key assumption that the random effect is zero mean encourages us to use fixed effects when possible to control for large contributors to mean differences. Modeling year as a fixed effect, presumably a grouped linear effect which gives a slope in value over time, also detrends data and improves estimates of residual variability. If you fit categorical effects for year, aliasing will occur and lead to singular, nonstable effects.

Comment: Given the econometrics tag, I doubt that OP is running random effects.  Doing so would imply that the year effect is orthogonal to all regressors, which is rarely justified in observational data.

Comment: Yea, I am not running REM. Ha

Comment: @generic_user ah. How do econometricians estimate panel data? Still the concept of reducing residual variance by explicitly controlling for dominant contributors to variance (precision adjustment), seems to be good practice in such cases.

Comment: Typically they're entirely projected-out by subtracting groupwise means of each variable from the original data, or by other procedures that are equivalent.  Numerically equivalent to a dummy variable for each group.  Given that the interest is typically on unbiased estimates of marginal effects, bias-variance tradeoff optimization is not pursued at all.